# How to get CSS style using JavaScript and change value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move the picture from the right end of the window to the left.
When I write the left and top values ​​myself, it works, but I want to read these values, and not enter them myself.

**The javascript code**

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', f, false);
window.addEventListener('keyup', f, false);
var img = document.getElementById("img_main");

var left = 1020;
var topw = 50;
console.log(left);
console.log(topw);

function f(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:
      topw -= 10;
      img.style.top = topw + 'px';
      break;
    case 40:
      topw += 10;
      img.style.top = topw + 'px';
      break;
    case 39:
      left += 10;
      img.style.left = left + 'px';
      break;
    case 37:
      left -= 10;
      img.style.left = left + 'px';
      break;

  }
}
```

**the CSS code**

```
#img_main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1020px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: @Andreas 
`var style = window.getComputedStyle(img);    
 var left=style.getPropertyValue('left');
 var topw=style.getPropertyValue('top');`
I did it, but the block does not move

Comment: `.getPropertyValue()` returns a _string_

Comment: @Andreas,yeah,returns 1020px,but i need only 1020

Comment: It should be easy to find a way how to convert a string into a real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parseInt to get the top and left value as integer, without the `'px'`:

```
   var style = window.getComputedStyle(img); 
   var left=parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('left')); 
   var topw=parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('top'));
```